# Hosting a Site with Windows Azure

Tags: web-hosting, azure

This is probably a ridiculously simple question, but is there a way for me to host a normal, static website on Windows Azure? I see on auzre.com that they do offer web hosting, but after trying to figure it out myself, and looking for some sort of tutorial, I can't figure out how to upload my files. I work with FTP and DNs stuff all the time, but Azure's really confusing me. I'm betting it's because it's overpowered for what I'm looking for, but I'd still like to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Azure allows three things - virtual machines, website, and a more complicated platform. [This](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/common-tasks/create-a-php-web-site) describes how to create a site for PHP, but applies to sites generally, then [this guide](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-manage-websites/) describes how to find out what you need to FTP your files.

Answer (score 0):

Azure is like any other cloud hosting services. Either you can create applications using their platform or make your own and upload. Since you can create virtual machines, install your OS and then install necessary ftp and dns apps on it and then go like you use the other hosting services.

Answer (score -2):

In normal web hosting, you just need to upload all your files via FTP to your root folder, but I have never used Azure, maybe you need to ask them. As I know Azure is good but more expensive than normal web hosting.

Comment: They could ask them, but they're asking here. You haven't really answered the question.

Comment: Not necessarily true that Azure is more expensive; in fact, my site is hosted both on azurewebsites.net (Free) and with discountasp.net (not free).